Number out of representable range: type FIXED[SB4] with Snowflake Python Connector
I have a typical ETL project where I am reading a csv file into a Pandas dataframe and need to write this DataFrame to a Snowflake table
  with og_snowflake_resource.get_connection() as sf_conn:
            write_pandas(conn=sf_conn, overwrite=False, df=raw_df, table_name=the_target_table_name,
                         auto_create_table=True,
                         database=SF_DATABASE, schema=my_schema_name, quote_identifiers=False)

Notice that I have used auto_create_table=True in order to automatically created table in snowflake. This is desirable.
Some of the columns in my input csv files are typed to python's Decimal. Such columns get created as NUMBER columns in snowflake
The code works fine for some files and then break for some. If I look at the schema of auto-created table, I can see the NUMBER typed columns are created with different precsions! :-

Now, if the subsequent CSV file has a Decimal value that can't fit in the NUMRIC column that was created in last runs, the operation fails ?
Question:- How can I instruct the write_pandas method to write the decimal values in Numeric column of a given fixed precision ?


can you not create the table beforehand and not use auto_create_table ?

show sample of actual data that you have issues with.

if created beforehand then ingested into snowflake do you still have the conversion issue ?

If I create the snowflake table before hand, then it works just fine. @ticktalk

@samhita The use case I am dealing with needs auto create table feature.

@ticktalk Can't share the exact data here. Let's say we have 2 csv files - file1.csv, file2.csv - ingested in that order. Assume the column in both files is an 'amount' column.
file1, amount = 100.45. --> Numeric(5,2)   (Auto Generated column type)
file2,amount = 1000000.45 --> Numeric(9,2) (Auto Generated column type)
The file2 amount won't fit in the earlier created Numeric(5,2). It would have worked if the file2 was ingested before file1.
